# need help with mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

1st piece of background inf : This is about cms which holds object - object relations and their sorting in single table, columns are object_id, parent_id and sorting order

2nd piece have query with several joins, which i want to sort by 2 parameters. One of those is sorting of the object itself and 2nd is the sorting order of its parent.

The query i have for now is:

```
SELECT obj_asset.*, object.headline AS title, oo.sort_order AS sort, op.sort_order FROM obj_asset 
JOIN object ON obj_asset.object_id = object.object_id 
JOIN object_object AS oo on obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
JOIN (SELECT sort_order from object_object WHERE object_id = (SELECT parent_id from object_object WHERE object_id = obj_asset.object_id )) AS op ON obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
WHERE obj_asset.profile_id = 140 AND obj_asset.rsvp_enabled = 1 AND object.is_published = 1 ORDER BY sort DESC;
```

And it does not work. This works fine though:

```
SELECT obj_asset.*, object.headline AS title, oo.sort_order AS sort, op.sort_order FROM obj_asset 
JOIN object ON obj_asset.object_id = object.object_id 
JOIN object_object AS oo on obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
JOIN (SELECT sort_order from object_object WHERE object_id = (SELECT parent_id from object_object WHERE object_id = 11111 )) AS op ON obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
WHERE obj_asset.profile_id = 140 AND obj_asset.rsvp_enabled = 1 AND object.is_published = 1 ORDER BY sort DESC;
```

The error i get is:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'obj_asset.object_id' in 'where clause'

How can i get it working?

Thanks!

EDIT: i could get around the problem, if i could come up with alternate way to include parents sorting into the query. IS there such a way?

Comment: Are you sure that you have object_id column in obj_asset table?

Comment: The error message is a pretty good clue in this instance. (You may have to use the `tablename.fieldname` naming style if the interpreter is attempting to use the wrong object_id field.) :-)

Comment: @KomarSerjio - yes i am - as you can see, its not the only place i have used same column&table and it works if i change it for actual id.
@middaparka - I understand why the error comes up - in the context of the inner select, there is no obj_asset.object_id as it has not been selected yet... But how can i fix this with just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already figured out, the problem is that you are trying to use a column from an outer query in a constraint of a subquery:

```
  (SELECT sort_order
      from object_object
      WHERE object_id = (SELECT parent_id
                         from object_object
                         WHERE object_id = obj_asset.object_id )
     )
```

This subquery can be rewritten, but it is not clear how when only looking at your original query.

There is probably an error in  your **original query** (reformatted):

```
SELECT obj_asset.*, object.headline AS title, oo.sort_order AS sort, op.sort_order
FROM obj_asset 
JOIN object ON obj_asset.object_id = object.object_id 
JOIN object_object AS oo on obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
JOIN (SELECT sort_order
      from object_object
      WHERE object_id = (SELECT parent_id
                         from object_object
                         WHERE object_id = obj_asset.object_id )
     ) AS op ON obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
WHERE obj_asset.profile_id = 140 AND obj_asset.rsvp_enabled = 1 AND object.is_published = 1 ORDER BY sort DESC;
```

The sub query named `op` is not used in any join or where clause.

My **best guess** is that you wanted to to the following:

```
SELECT obj_asset.*, object.headline AS title, oo.sort_order AS sort, op.sort_order
FROM obj_asset 
JOIN object ON obj_asset.object_id = object.object_id 
JOIN object_object AS oo on obj_asset.object_id = oo.object_id
JOIN (SELECT sort_order, o2.object_id
    from object_object as o1
    INNER JOIN object_object as o2 ON o1.object_id = o2.parent_id
    ) AS op ON obj_asset.object_id = op.object_id
WHERE obj_asset.profile_id = 140 AND obj_asset.rsvp_enabled = 1 AND object.is_published = 1 ORDER BY sort DESC;
```

Comment: man, i could kiss you right now :P. Thats exactly what i needed. Only one mistake - was supposed to be (SELECT o1.sort_order.... Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped - no kissing please, upvoting is enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery doesn't include obj_asset in the FROM clause.

```
(SELECT parent_id FROM object_object WHERE object_id = obj_asset.object_id )
```

Get that part running, and you should have better luck with the whole thing.

Just a hint... if you put some more newlines and indentations in your SQL statements it will be easier for you to spot problems.

Comment: meh? yeah.. i know thats where the problem is. I just cant think of any way to fix it atm.

Comment: oops, I meant FROM clause.  Try `SELECT parent_id FROM object_object, obj_asset WHERE object_object.object_id = obj_asset.object_id`

Comment: Like i answered to SVGreg - that would rise new problems, as parent_id is not column of obj_asset and if it were, then select would return multiple rows, where i only need one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to type this (include obj_asset to FROM):

```
(SELECT parent_id FROM object_object, obj_asset  WHERE object_object.object_id = obj_asset.object_id )
```

but not this:

```
(SELECT parent_id from object_object WHERE object_id = obj_asset.object_id )
```

Comment: nope. that creates whole new bunch of problems as there is no parent_id in obj_asset and it will also return more than 1 row.